# Xposed module, ClassNotFoundException dynamically loaded class

Tags: java, android, hook, classloader, xposed

I currently have this code in my Xposed module:

```
public class Test implements IXposedHookLoadPackage, IXposedHookZygoteInit {

@Override
public void initZygote(StartupParam startupParam) throws Throwable {
    XposedBridge.log("ZYGOTE INIT");
}

@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(final XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {

    if(lpparam.packageName.equals("com.somerandomapp")) {

        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(Application.class, "attach", Context.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

                XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("java.lang.Class", lpparam.classLoader,
                        "forName", String.class, boolean.class, ClassLoader.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
                    @Override
                    protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param1) throws Throwable {

                        if(((String)param1.args[0]).equals("com.alibaba.wireless.security.mainplugin.SecurityGuardMainPlugin")) {

                            Class clazz = XposedHelpers.findClass("SecurityGuardMainPlugin", (ClassLoader)param1.args[2]);
                            XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.alibaba.wireless.security.a.l.a", (ClassLoader)param1.args[2], "a", clazz, new XC_MethodHook() {
                                @Override
                                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

                                    XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("com.alibaba.wireless.security.a.l.a", lpparam.classLoader, "getSecurityToken", new XC_MethodHook() {
                                        @Override
                                        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                                            XposedBridge.log("Token: " + param.getResult());
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

I am trying to hook the method `com.alibaba.wireless.security.a.l.a#a` after `SecurityGuardMainPlugin` gets dynamically loaded by the app at runtime.  I am however getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.  This is strange because as you can see in the code, after the `Class#forName` method is executed I check to see if `SecurityGuardMainPlugin` was loaded and it seems it is.

I have also tried with `lpparam.classloader` in the last two `findAndHookMethod` calls with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are intercepting [Class.forName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) and assuming it is indeed intercepting something, you don't need to find the class, you already have it in your `param1.getResult()`. Just use `XposedBridge.hookMethod(param1.getResult(), yourHook)` directly on that.

Also note that it is generally a bad practice to hook methods from within your hooks. Make sure if the members aren't already hooked before registering a new hook.